# Solving ODE using Wronskian

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

*Solve $$t^2y''-2y = 3t^2-1, \: t>0$$
using that $y_1 = t^2, \: y_2 = t^{-1}$ form a fundamental set of solutions to the corresponding homogenous equation.*

**My attempt at a solution:**

First rewrite the equation as $$y''-2t^{-2}y = 3-t^{-2}$$
We get the Wronskian $W(y_1, y_2) = -3$. A particular solution is thus obtained by adding the following two integrals: 
$$\frac{t^2}{3} \int_{t_0}^{t} s^{-1}(3-s^{-2}) ds = \frac{t^2}{3} \int_{t_0}^{t} 3s^{-1}-s^{-3} ds $$
$$\frac{-1}{3t} \int_{t_0}^{t} s^2(3-s^{-2}) ds = \frac{-1}{3t} \int_{t_0}^{t} 3s^2-1 \: ds$$
We thus get $$Y_p = \frac{t^2}{3} \big[3ln(s)+\frac{s^{-2}}{2} \big]^{t}_{t_0}-\frac{1}{3t} \big[s^3-s \big]^{t}_{t_0}$$

This is somehow, for some appropriate value $t_0>0$, supposed to be equal to $$\frac{1}{2}+t^2ln(t)$$ but I can't see how the term $$-\frac{t^2}{3}$$vanishes.

I just don't see how. Any help?

Comment: Recall, $y(t) = y_h(t) + y_p(t)$. It gets absorbed as part of the $c_1 t^2$ term from the homogeneous solution, since we have $\left(c_1 - \dfrac{1}{3}\right) t^2 = c_1 t^2$ (just another constant).

Comment: Oh that is true. Thank you.